# Can we make an internal Google API call? By installing all pre-requirements locally for OCR?

Tags: api, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, artificial-intelligence, ocr

## Trying to implement OCR in bank environment but challenge is, we don't have access to internet connection for security reasons.

"Handwritten and scanned document to be digitalised"

open source like Tesseract OCR are good for normal English but most of our documents are in handwritten Arabic. I have tried Google OCR API [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/handwriting) which has AI & ML works better with Arabic hand written and more accuracy.
I have google cloud, created storage,and uploaded hand written Arabic image in bucket then executed internal command in cloud terminal that is giving proper result.

External API Call:

```
curl -X POST \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
     --data "{
      'requests': [
        {
          'image': {
            'source': {
              'imageUri': 'gs://vision-api-handwriting-ocr-bucket/handwriting_image.png'
            }
          },
          'features': [
            {
              'type': 'DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }" "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate"
```

Internal Google Cloud cmd:

```
gcloud ml vision detect-document "gs://vision-api-handwriting-ocr-bucket/handwriting_image.png"
```

The above internal google cloud cmd code works fine in my case. The same i need to implement in the local system. **Is there any possibility to install same Google cloud environment and their OCR engine in local? If its priced also no problem ready to pay and buy.** Resource like high configured servers, networks everything already available in our bank.

Comment: I seriously doubt it. You will need to contact you Google Account Rep to get a definitive answer.

Comment: Abbyy API Is good for offline OCR https://www.abbyy.com/en-us/ocr-sdk/

Answer (score 1):

it's been a while since this was posted, but just in case, there is a solution available now.
You may check this **OCR on-prem** application on Google Cloud Marketplace which can be deployed as a container to any GKE cluster:
https://cloud.google.com/vision/on-prem

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. we are using DL techniques and tesseract as of now for OCR. let me check on the OCR on-prem application as well.